# System of differential equations: where did I got wrong?

Tags: linear-algebra, integration, ordinary-differential-equations, systems-of-equations

I have the system:

$$x_1'=2x_1-x_2+e^{2t}\\ 
x_2'=4x_1+2x_2+4$$

So I searched for the homogeneous solutions and got:

$$X_H=c_1e^{2t}
        \left(\begin{matrix}
         \cos 2t  \\
         2\sin 2t\\
        \end{matrix}\right)+c_2e^{2t} \left(\begin{matrix}
         \sin 2t  \\
         -2\cos 2t\\
        \end{matrix}\right)
$$

Then I have to set:
$$ e^{2t}\left(\begin{matrix}
         \cos 2t  & \sin 2t\\
         2\sin 2t& -2\cos2\\
        \end{matrix}\right)
 \left(\begin{matrix}
         c_1'  \\
         c_2'\\
        \end{matrix}\right)= \left(\begin{matrix}
         e^{2t}  \\
         4\\
        \end{matrix}\right)
$$

I spent like two hours solving the resulting integrals, and checked with wolfram (they seemed okay) and got:

$$X_P=\left(\frac {\sin 2t}{2}-\frac {\sin 2t+ \cos 2t}{2e^{2t}}\right)e^t\left(\begin{matrix} \cos2t\\ 2\sin2t\end{matrix}\right)+\left( \frac {-\cos 2t}{2} + \frac {\cos2t-\sin2t}{2e^{2t}}\right) e^{2t}\left(\begin{matrix} \sin 2t \\ -2\cos2t\end{matrix}\right)$$

But then I checked and this didn't solve the system... Did I miss any step?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your next equations are correct :
$$X_H=c_1e^{2t}
        \left(\begin{matrix}
         \cos 2t  \\
         2\sin 2t\\
        \end{matrix}\right)+c_2e^{2t} \left(\begin{matrix}
         \sin 2t  \\
         -2\cos 2t\\
        \end{matrix}\right)
$$

$$ e^{2t}\left(\begin{matrix}
         \cos 2t  & \sin 2t\\
         2\sin 2t& -2\cos 2t\\
        \end{matrix}\right)
 \left(\begin{matrix}
         c_1'  \\
         c_2'\\
        \end{matrix}\right)= \left(\begin{matrix}
         e^{2t}  \\
         4\\
        \end{matrix}\right)
$$
Then, one cannot check your calculus because all the details are not written. The mistake is probably easy to find because there is a term $e^t$ instead of $e^{2t}$ in your final result. No $e^t$ should appear.

I obtained :
$$x_1=c_1 e^{2t}\cos(2t)+c_2 e^{2t}\sin(2t)-\frac{1}{2}$$
$$x_2=2c_1 e^{2t}\sin(2t)-2c_2 e^{2t}\cos(2t)-1+e^{2t}$$

Hint :

$$ 
 \left(\begin{matrix}
         c_1'  \\
         c_2'\\
        \end{matrix}\right)=
\left(\begin{matrix}
         \cos 2t  & \sin 2t\\
         2\sin 2t & -2\cos 2t\\
        \end{matrix}\right)^{-1}
 \left(\begin{matrix}
         1  \\
         4 e^{-2t}\\
        \end{matrix}\right)
$$

$$ 
 \left(\begin{matrix}
         c_1'  \\
         c_2'\\
        \end{matrix}\right)=
\left(\begin{matrix}
         \cos 2t +2e^{-2t}\sin 2t\\
         \sin 2t -2e^{-2t}\cos 2t\\
 \end{matrix}\right)
$$
Then integration leads to $c_1$ and $c_2$

$$ 
 \left(\begin{matrix}
         c_1  \\
         c_2  \\
        \end{matrix}\right)=
\frac{1}{2}e^{-2t}
\left(\begin{matrix}
         -\cos 2t -\sin 2t +e^{2t}\sin 2t\\
         \cos 2t -\sin 2t -e^{2t}\cos 2t\\
 \end{matrix}\right)+
\left(\begin{matrix}
         C_1\\
         C_2\\
 \end{matrix}\right)
$$

Note that all this stuff isn't necessary to find a particular solution : just a bit of intuition and/or "trial and error" approach, on can find the terms $(-\frac{1}{2} \: ,\: -1+e^{2t})$ to be added to the homogeneous solution.

Comment: Could you give me  some insights into how you calculated $c_1(t), c_2(t)$? I keep failling...

Comment: See the addition to my first answer.